# Which operations update last access time?

Tags: windows, winapi, filesystems, nfs, ntfs

Assuming given filesystem is tracking Last Access Time (aka `atime`) -- which operations on a file cause `atime` to update?

As far as I know:

- opening existing file (and subsequent closing related handle/fd) does **not** update `atime`
- reading/writing file will update `atime` (I wonder if `read-0-bytes` operation does that)
- reading file security descriptor (via related Win32 API) does **not** update `atime` or other file attributes

Is there an exhaustive list of operations that update `atime`?

Comment: If access time is enabled (it's disabled by default on NTFS) then opening an existing file and either reading or writing any data will update it. Nothing else does as far as I know. There's also a magic cookie you can pass when opening the file to prevent the access time being updated.

Comment: The behavior to prevent the last access time from being modified isn't enabled when opening a file, but rather in a subsequent call to [SetFileTime](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfiletime), passing a special value for `lpLastAccessTime`.

Comment: Ah yes you're right, it's been a long time since I've looked at this.

Comment: @JonathanPotter there is also enumerating a directory and (probably) reading/writing/creating/removing alternate streams

Comment: @C.M. Enumerating a directory won't affect the files in the directory. Not sure about the directory's timestamp itself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The last access time includes the last time the file or directory was **written to**, **read from**, or, in the case of executable files, **run**.

Other operations, like accessing the file to retrieve properties to show in Explorer
or some other viewer, accessing the file to retrieve its icon etc. don't update last access time.

Refer to "[`GetFileTime` - `lpLastAccessTime`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-getfiletime)", "[How do I access a file without updating its last-access time?](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20111010-00/?p=9433)"

**Update:** Add test results of read/write 0 bytes and read/write 1 bytes.

Code used for testing:

```
void GetLastAccessTime(HANDLE hFile)
{
    FILETIME ftAccess;
    SYSTEMTIME stUTC, stLocal;

    printf("Get last access time\n");

    // Retrieve the file times for the file.
    if (!GetFileTime(hFile, NULL, &ftAccess, NULL))
        return;

    // Convert the last-write time to local time.
    FileTimeToSystemTime(&ftAccess, &stUTC);
    SystemTimeToTzSpecificLocalTime(NULL, &stUTC, &stLocal);

    // Build a string showing the date and time.
    wprintf(
        L"%02d/%02d/%d  %02d:%02d \n",
        stLocal.wMonth, stLocal.wDay, stLocal.wYear,
        stLocal.wHour, stLocal.wMinute);
}

int main()
{
    HANDLE tFile = INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE;

    printf("Open file\n");
    // Open file
    tFile = CreateFile(L"C:\\Users\\ritah\\Desktop\\test1.txt", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL, OPEN_EXISTING, 0, NULL);
    if (INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE == tFile)
    {
        printf("CreateFile fails with error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Sleep 60 seconds\n");
    Sleep(60000);

    GetLastAccessTime(tFile);

    // Read 0 bytes
    printf("Read 0 bytes\n");
    WCHAR redBuf[10];
    DWORD redBytes = 0;
    if(!ReadFile(tFile, redBuf, 0, &redBytes, NULL))
    {
        printf("ReadFile fails with error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Sleep 60 seconds\n");
    Sleep(60000);

    GetLastAccessTime(tFile);

    // Write 0 bytes
    printf("Write 0 bytes\n");
    WCHAR writeBuf[] = L"write test";
    DWORD writeBytes = 0;
    if(!WriteFile(tFile, writeBuf, 0, &writeBytes, NULL))
    {
        printf("WriteFile fails with error: %d\n", GetLastError());
        getchar();
        return 0;
    }

    printf("Sleep 60 seconds\n");
    Sleep(60000);

    GetLastAccessTime(tFile);

    getchar();
}
```

[image]

[image]

So, **read/write `0` bytes doesn't update last access time**.

Comment: what about accessing (or changing) alternate streams? what about read/write-zero-bytes requests/API calls? What about changing security data? other metadata?

Comment: @C.M. Read/write-zero-bytes **doesn't** update last access time. For security data, I test changing access right, it also **doesn't** update last access time. It is hard to test all possible operations, if you found any operation go against the document states about last access time, feel free let me know.